# Loading Flash object in Facebook tab causes inline text to change in Safari

Tags: facebook, flash, debugging, fonts, safari

If you create a new app in Facebook pointing to an HTML page with only the code below, you will see an obvious change in font-smoothing in the paragraph after the Flash object loads. This only occurs in WebKit browsers and only in Facebook.

```
<!doctype html>
<head></head>
<body style="background-color: #333">
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="100%" height="170" id="movie_name" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="http://edmullen.net/flash/BBC1.swf"/>
    <param name="wMode" value="transparent" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://edmullen.net/flash/BBC1.swf" width="100%" height="170">
    <param name="movie" value="http://edmullen.net/flash/BBC1.swf"/>
    <param name="wMode" value="transparent" />
     </object>
    </object>
    <p style="color: red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p style="color: white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I've replicated this with multiple swf files. I even went so far as to embed the Flash object in an `iframe`, but the bug persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an old bug on the webkit site explaining this behavior. Basically, the loading of the object causes a repaint event, and on the second pass the font renderer does not return the same result as the first. Here is the reference:

- [Font antialiasing (smoothing) changes when elements are rendered into compositing layers](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23364)